# How to install Mahout (Hadoop) on a localhost (mac)

Tags: installation, hadoop, localhost, mamp, mahout

I'm interested in playing around with Mahout a bit (and by proxy Hadoop), I'm wondering if anyone has experience installing these projects locally. I know that Mahout is implemented in JAVA, but I'm not really sure about Hadoop. I read a bit about using them on amazon or rackspace, but I have my heart set on testing locally.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to download or install Hadoop to use Mahout locally, even its Hadoop-based bits. You do need to use Maven, which will manage downloading the dependencies. The Mahout command line, and examples involving `mvn`, should all just work.